# Changing a textbox based on a dropdown html array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am finding issues doing this, I am curious if its because I am using HTML form arrays.

Anywho so heres my problem, I want to change a dropdown box and have it change the text in a textbox to that value! Sound's simple enough right?

Well here's my failed attempt:

```
<select id=discount[0] name=discount[0]>
    <option value=1>option 1</option>
    <option value=2>option 2</option>
</select>
<input type=text id=postdiscount[0]>
```

And my JS:

```
$("#discount[0]").change(function () {

        $("#postdiscount[0]").val(this.value);

});
```

JSFiddle if you guys wanna play about:
http://jsfiddle.net/t75ut97f/3/

EDIT: 
Has nothing to do with form items being in an array :X!

Comment: You need to escape the `[]` in the `jQuery` selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets, then just use `this.value`

```
$("#discount\\[0\\]").change(function () {

    $("#postdiscount\\[0\\]").val(this.value);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t75ut97f/2/